# asp.net webapi url to identify same resource

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I want to be able to identify a resource by different id types. for example:

GET http://example.com/customers/internalId=34 to go to

```
public Customer GetByInternalId(int internalId){...}
```

and 
GET http://example.com/customers/externalId='JohnDoe' to go to

```
public Customer GetByExternalId(string externalId){...}
```

I know I can do this by having some parsing logic in a generic controller method but I don't want to do that. How do I achieve this using the routing feature of asp.net webapi if that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you try and avoid doing what you are suggesting.  Creating two distinct URIs for the same resource will make it harder to use caching.  Instead I would suggest using one URL to redirect to the other.

e.g.

```
> GET /customers/34
< 200 OK


> GET /Customers?name=JohnDoe
< 303 See Other
< Location: http://example.com/customers/34
```

Comment: Thanks Darren. I've seen that answer before. I am trying to do what linked in does here:https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api and would like to know if such routing is possible with WebApi.

Comment: @darthjit  For sure it is possible with WebAPI because you can replace the routing component and implement it yourself.  Whether existing routing mechanism can do it, I don't know because I would never attempt to do such a thing.  Using the tilde to return the  "current profile" is an especially dumb thing for Linked in to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods do not make much of a sense, why would you return void from a method that begins with Get....?

Also, these routes:

```
http://example.com/customers/internalId=34
http://example.com/customers/externalId='JohnDoe
```

Are invalid from MVC/Web API perspective. This is how they should look like:

```
http://example.com/customers?internalId=34
http://example.com/customers?externalId=John
```

Default Web API routing should differentiate between the two and route it to different actions.

EDIT:

Create action with the following template:

```
[HttpGet]
public string InternalId(int id)
{
    return id.ToString();
}
```

Define route for Web Api:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Weird",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}={id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This allows you to write:

```
http://localhost:7027/values/internalId=12
```

Try it...

Then you can just add another method:

```
[HttpGet]
public string ExternalId(string id)
{
    return id;
}
```

And this:

```
http://localhost:7027/values/externalId=bob
```

Will work as well.

Clearly name of my controller is ValuesController as I've just tested this with default Web Api template.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in methods. While I realize that query strings will work, that is not what I am looking for. I would like to do what linked in has done here: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api , 
  http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=abcdefg   ,   
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=<public-profile-url>

Comment: I've updated my post with how you can do what you're trying to do. I believe you'll get the idea if you pay close attention to the route I've defined.